# Obtener resta total de una columna sql server

Tags: sql

Quisiera saber como puedo obtener la resta total de una columna en `TSql`. Es decir, así como se utiliza la función `SUM()` para sumar una columna, quisiera saber como hacerlo para la resta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo restar los registros de mi columna monto planificado.

Comment: ¿Cómo se calcula, a mano y paso por paso, una resta total?

Comment: sabias que si sumas numeros negativos, es como si restaras ;)

Comment: Pero en código como sería eso? intenté pasando la suma a negativo pero no me funcionó, como sería la forma correcta?

Comment: Si quieres recibir una buena ayuda que solucione lo que planteas, deberías de modificar la pregunta para que disponga de un buen escenario y mostrar lo que has intentado y lo que esperas de la solución aportada. [ask].

Comment: Cuando dices restar, quieres tomar un número como base/referencia y restarle todos los demás?

Comment: Si multiplicas cada numero por -1, es como si fueran negativos.. no?

Comment: tienes algún tipo de identificador que sirve para ordenar a los montos? con el fin de saber cuál es el primer monto_planificado

Comment: Ya tienes datos de prueba, pero sería mejor que los incluyeras como texto y no como imagen. También necesitas mostrar el resultado esperado sobre esos datos de prueba. Otro punto es que parece que no comprendes el principio básico de la resta que es el de obtener la diferencia entre dos números o reducir un numero respecto a otro. No existe tal cosa como una resta total porque básicamente son conceptos opuestos. Necesitas explicar claramente lo que intentas hacer porque nadie lo sabe.